# Obj-m command not found

Tags: linux, module

I have this primer assignment that I have to run inside a Linux VM (Version 2.6), and I'm trying to take this file

test_module.c

```
/*
*   test module.
*/

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/config.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init initialization_routine(void) {

printk ("Hello, world!\n");

return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_routine(void) {

printk ("Unloading module!\n");
}

module_init(initialization_routine);
module_exit(cleanup_routine);
```

And then I should be able to use the make command on this make file

makefile

```
    make:
         obj-m += test_module.o
```

But it keeps giving me the error obj-m not found.  I've looked online, and can't seem to find anything.  Is there something I must install in order to get the object module command?  Is it something i have to do with gcc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `obj-m` as a command when it's not, it shouldn't be listed after a target as you're doing.

The easiest way to compile your module is to follow [this guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN181), or in your case just copy their simple makefile which makes it quite convenient to build it;

```
obj-m += test_module.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but i am relatively new to linux. Can you tell what to do with above code. Do i have to save it somewhere or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is your case, but often "obj-m: not found" occurs when user try run file that contains "... make: obj-m += test_module.o". 
Instead, put "... make: obj-m += ..."  content in "Makefile" and run command "make" in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

-->You may write a C program as below:

test_mod.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk("Hello All\n This is a test init\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk("Good Bye");
}
```

--> make object file:

```
echo "obj-m := test_mod.o" > Makefile
```

--> compile by running :

`make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules`

--> load your module as below:

`insmod ./test_mod.ko`

see the output:

`dmesg | tail`

--> unload module:
`rmmod test_mod.ko`

Answer (score 0):

It says command not found because its not a command.

run `echo "obj-m := test_mod.o" > Makefile`

and then compile it as below:

`make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules`